# JS Functions Work Separately But Not Together

Tags: javascript, function

I'm using two functions to shift the background position and to zoom div's background. Here they are:

```
(function(shifting) {

    var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".shiftparallax"),
        speed = -0.05;

    window.onscroll = function() {
        [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el, i) {

            var windowXOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                elBackgrounPos = (windowXOffset * speed) + "px";
            console.log(elBackgrounPos);
            el.style.backgroundPositionY = elBackgrounPos;

        });
    };

})();


(function(zooming) {
    var parallaxfacts = document.querySelectorAll(".parallaxfacts"),
        constantsize = 100;
    speed = -0.03;
    window.onscroll = function() {

        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            [].slice.call(parallaxfacts).forEach(function(el, i) {

                var windowXOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                    elBackgrounScale = (windowXOffset / 950 * constantsize) + "%";

                el.style.backgroundSize = elBackgrounScale;

            });
        }
    };

})();
```

The problem is that I need them both to run at the same time but they only run separately. If they are both written like that - the second one runs only and the first one does nothing. If I remove the second one, the first one starts working. I've got a bit rusty in JS lately so I can't figure it out. is there any way to make them both work?

Comment: Please show how you're calling the functions and under what conditions.

Comment: @Difster They're IIFE (they call themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning to `window.onscroll` twice. That means the second handler "unregisters" the first.

You can use `addEventListener` to listen to the event in both functions:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() { /* function 1*/ });
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() { /* function 2*/ });
```

Comment: That did the thing. I had no idea they cancel each other. Thank you!

Comment: It's like any other property; if you `a = {}; a.x = 1; a.x = 2;`, `x` is `2` at the end because properties can only have one value.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the window.onscroll event

try this two lines:

```
window.onscroll = el => console.log ('first');
window.onscroll = el => console.log ('second');
```

use the following code...

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',  el => console.log ('firstlistener'));
window.addEventListener('scroll',  el => console.log ('secondlistener'));
```

Comment: Don’t use `el` here. It’s used as a variable in an inner function.

Comment: yes you can also write:
`window.addEventListener('scroll', () => console.log ('secondlistener'));`